# Alternative to event.srcElement.id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Currently I have a function that works perfectly for IE, Chrome and Safari in order to get the ID name of a textbox I'm placing a focus on within a Gridview.

```
function onTextFocus() {
        alert(event.srcElement.id);
    }
```

The function is called upon during a RowDataBound for the gridview:

```
protected void ItemGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Attributes.Add("onfocus", "onTextFocus();");            
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work for Firefox as it doesn't recognize srcElement.  So I'm looking for an alternative that would work for all browsers.  After scouring Google I came up with these alternatives but I either get an undefined error or ReferenceError.  Any ideas why?

```
function onTextFocus() {
        alert(this.id);
        alert(event.currentTarget.id); 
        alert(event.target.id);    
        alert(event.currentTarget); 
        alert(event.target);                          
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        alert($(obj).attr("id"));            
        alert($(this).id);
        alert($(this).get(0).id);            
        alert($(this).prop("id"));
    }
```

Comment: Show how and where you are using the method

Comment: Is the Problem Solved, can or do you need some more assistance?

Answer (score 9):

Instead `event.srcElement` use `event.target`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Answer (score 3):

**Begin Update**:
*Now that I see the dotNet Code:*

```
protected void ItemGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Attributes.Add("onfocus", "onTextFocus(event);");            
    }
}
```

*If you add the `event` parameter it should pass it*

> But depends on **what** you really want to do there might be a better way.

**End Update**

**The short answer** is use `event.target` here is the specification on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target it shows it is supported by the major browser. In your case you have to add the parameter `event`in your event-handling function.

```
function onTextFocus(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
}
```

if you don't declare the `event` Parameter, you cannot access it.
*(It also depends on how you are binding the event)*

With standard Javascript (check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), short example here:

```js
   window.onload = function(){
    
     document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('focus', onclick1);

    function onclick1(event){
        console.info(event.target.id);
    }
 };
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

with jQuery (check out this link http://api.jquery.com/on/) Short example here:

```js
$( function(){
    
     $("#test1").on('focus', onclick1);

    function onclick1(event){
        console.info(event.target.id);
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test1" />
```

**Update:**
*(btw.: You could use the global window.event property, which holds the current event, BUT it is recomended to use the event which is passed to the event handler)*

Answer (score 1):

try with `e.target.id`. you should use it instead of `event.target.id`, which is already deprecated. if you are trying to get properties from an html element when clicking it or similar, you can also try calling it by value with `e.target.value`. hope it helps someone.